# J is null in TinyMce.js

Tags: tinymce

I use tinymce on my website and I always run into this annoying j is null.
In my template file I originally had the init method out in the open like in the example...

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple"   
});
</script>
```

But in the error console of Firefox I see something that says "j is null" and the reference is somewhere within the tiny_mce.js file. 
Any help is appreciated.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tinymce bug. Internally, the tinymce code uses a `<span id="mce_marker"></span>` to remember the caret-position when pasting. when validating the resulting fragment, after the paste, the span is deemed invalid and removed, thus breaking the code by removing the marker.
This issue will be fixed in the next official tinymce minor release. There are some workarounds for this kind of issue. One is to add to add `id` and `mce-data-type` attribute to `spans` [as valid elements (init setting)](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements). Example:

```
// The valid_elements option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.
    valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style]," +
    "a[name|href|target|title]," +
    "#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u" +
    "-span[data-mce-type]",
```